# Parameter count mismatch in property.GetValue()

Tags: c#

I'm getting the

> parameter count mismatch

error. It occurs at the `if` clause. My code:

```
private Dictionary<string,string> ObjectToDict(Dictionary<string, string> dict, object obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
            dict["{{" + property.Name + "}}"] = property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
    }
    return dict;
}
```

It's strange because it works just fine when I add the `property` value to the dictionary, but not when I'm testing if it's `null` in the `if` clause.

All the questions I've found were putting an incorrect number of arguments into the function call, but AFAIK there's nothing different between my two calls.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because your object type has an [indexer "property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) and you are passing null to the index parameter on the *GetValue* call.

Either remove the indexed property or filter out the indexed properties from your *properties* variable, for example:

```
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);
```