# In a ListView, how can I open different URLs depending on which list item I have tapped on?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin.forms

I am using ListView from Xamarin.Forms for my project. 
I have a `List<MyObject>`, where each object MyObject has an individual URL property. 
The List is used as the ItemsSource for the ListView.
How can I let each list item open the URL it has been assigned to, when clicked on?

Comment: Have you tried using reflexion on your list? Or maybe a simple foreach-loop?

Comment: @AdrianEfford What do you mean with reflexion? I didn't find anything about it on google.

Comment: Reflection sorry... Here a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234236/reflection-on-list-and-printing-values

Comment: You are looking for OnClickEvent for list item,  here is how you do it https://www.codemahal.com/video/adding-click-events-to-a-listview-in-android-with-xamarin/

Comment: @Ali That's for Xamarin Native, I need Xamarin Forms.

Comment: See the answer from Jason, but native is really easy to convert to Forms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `ItemSelected` event

```
protected void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
  var item = (MyObject)args.SelectedItem;
  var url = item.Url;

  Device.OpenUri(url);
}
```